# Wifi not working (Greyed out in NetworkManager)

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Things I've tried

First off let me start by saying sudo ifconfig shows it up. and rfkill shows it unblocked. And im doing this all from a nonroot account. Also wifi DOES work on pure debian.

`sudo rfkill unblock all`

`sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

`sudo pico /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.org`

*And change allow_avtive to yes*

Then finally I tried

```
sudo -i
sudo ps -A | grep lightdm
startx
```

I could not figure out how to allow root log in in order to debug.. So the last command kills the x server and restarts it as root to achieve more or less that effect...

EDIT: `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` shows my wifi card can see my access point :(

EDIT2 (Due to reply):

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 modu 11g`
->

```
Error for wireless request "Set Modulation" (8B2F) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

`iwconfig wlan0 channel 11`
->

```
Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted.
```

About going into network manager I don't know what you mean by that? `At the top right` I have nothing in the top right but the close button to my browser window. So i went to the network settings by clicking the icon on my bottum bar but the option IGNORE IPV6 can only be applied to networks i create, I want wifi to scan on its own like it use to.

`I will add I can connect to wifi over the terminal.`

And the last step i just did it for kicks... I know thats VERY dumb to do but anyway its the only command that worked lol... by worked i mean no error returned.

NEW EDIT:
I just tried reinstalling network-manager. Yet after installing the plasma-nm widget it still has the wifi checkbox greyed out, and doesnt scan networks.

NEW EDIT (based on comment):

`lspci -nn | grep 0280`
->

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
```

`iwconfig`
->

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=16 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
```

Comment: Please show the results of: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: iwconfig. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i hate to do this... but it solved my problem so im doign it.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd

sudo service network-manager stop

sudo service wicd start
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the parameter of wireless driver as follows and check the reported issuse.

> change 802.11bgn to 802.11bg.

iwconfig wlan0 modu 11g

> change the wep encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.

wpa-pairwise CCMP

> Set your wireless channel in the router to 1 or 11 then save the router configuration and reboot it.

iwconfig wlan0 channel #

> Go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections>wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore.

Now open the terminal CTRL+ALT+_T then copy and paste the following code one line at a time for accuracy:

```
echo "options rtl8192ce swenc=1 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192ce.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8192ce
sudo modprobe -v rtl8192ce
```

IF the issue persists, try compiling new driver. Hope this helps!

Comment: Why do you believe his wireless driver is rtl8192ce?

Comment: @chili555 It's an example code as per our test environment.

Comment: However, if he hasn't that specific driver, those steps do nothing but waste time.

Comment: @chili555 yes got it. Will rectify it from next post.Thank you.

Comment: =( still need help.. what do you mean go into network manager at top right. I went instead to the bottom right and clicked on network settigns but the only way i can set IPV6 to ignore is by creating a network.. i want the wifi to be able to scan networks on its own. Why did this randomly break? Do you have any clue? It use to all work.. first I had to make a script to unblock via rfkill, then another to do ifconfid wlan0 up, then i had to modify policies.. its like the mroe time passes the more things i have to do to get it to work lol