# A complete guide for backing up Ubuntu via the tar command?

Tags: tar, reinstall

I have given up on solving my wifi problem which can be seen here -> [Wifi not working (Greyed out in NetworkManager)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537495/wifi-not-working-greyed-out-in-networkmanager)

So I am going to reinstall kubuntu 14.05.

However this is like my 20th time doing this and every single time I make a tarball I have some kind of problem extracting that tarball on the new install.. I was wondering is someone knows a very specific way to make it work without problems? Or knows of a guide.. I have been to the usual guides and they never seem to quite work perfectly..

The steps I usually take are more less just

`cd /`

`tar zgvf backup.tar.gz ./*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run these commands as root:

```
cd /
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

This will preserve everything, but not `/proc`, `/sys`, `/mnt`, `/run`, `/dev`, `/media/*`, `backup.tar.gz`, and other partitions.

Please note that other partitions will not be saved in the archive. For instance, your `/home` folder will not be saved if it is not on the main filesystem.

---

To restore (As root):

1. You may restore only selected files/folders.
2. You may restore from a LiveCD/LiveUSB. Instructions for this are below:

First off, cd to `/media`: `cd /media`

Now, run this magic command:

```
tar -xvpzf /path/to/backup.tar.gz -C /media/myDrive --numeric-owner
```

You may need to do other things, but this is specified in the Wiki post linked below.

Read [this Wiki post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) for a more detailed explanation.

---

***In this case, a full backup may (and probably is) overboard and won't help.***

If your problem is in fact how you describe it, the problem is probably in one of your `/etc` configs. I recommend that you only copy your important files from your home directory to a USB drive.

Comment: Ok i never tried --one-file-system. I will re-read that wiki AGAIN.. thanks.

Comment: That should work, but are you sure you *want* it? This will restore all your system-wide files, so if you have a configuration problem and are reinstalling to solve it, you will restore your problem too. Normally you just save the `/home` hierarchy --- and sometime not even that but just the not-hidden home files, given that the problem could really be in one of your ".dot" file in your home dir.

Comment: @Rmano -- Good point. Adding.